# Have a "apprequests" notification redirect to a website

Tags: facebook, dialog, request

I have the FB request dialog (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)  setup so my users can invite friends.  Everything is working fine, it sends a notification to the user(s) and all, but I want to have it so that when the recipient clicks the notification or 'jewel' it takes them to my website instead of a FB page/app.

Comment: You are deceiving your users... Accepting an apprequest means the user acted on an invitation to a **facebook application**, not an invitatin to your site.  Place a link to your site inside your app and then use  @DannyKK's solution.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it's not possible to set the redirect uri on a request. The only way to do this is to have a js redirect on you application canvas.

top.location.href='YOUR_SITE'

Comment: how can I set my application canvas ?