# Facebook dialog request URL

Tags: php, facebook, dialog, request

I'm using facebook dialog request to send invite to my friend.

When my friend click my invite,this is how the URL is

http://apps.facebook.com/appname/?request_ids=w453sdfdsfdzfsa5345324&ref=notif&notif_t=app_request

But,i've a functionality which checks whether the user has liked the page or not.

My else part shows,if user has n't like the page.When my friends click my invite,it is showing him the else part because it is out of facebook brand page.

When my friends click my invite,the URL should be like this

https://www.facebook.com/pagename?sk=app_32432432234&request_ids=w453sdfdsfdzfsa5345324&ref=notif&notif_t=app_request

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: @lgy:Is there any way to do this? Can you give me a better solution?

Comment: @Shawn E Carter:can you help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application requests (per their name) automatically redirect to the canvas URL of the application that created the Requests dialog (see the *User Response* section in [the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)). There is [no way to change this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7817843/113527) to your Facebook Page or any other URL.

A possible solution would be to check whether the `request_ids` parameter exists after a user visits your application, and then automatically redirect users to your Facebook page after deleting their apprequest.

Comment: :How do generally people check whether user has like a page or not ,when he comes through invite.User should n't go out of the page.